# Can I disable specific days in DatePicker in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, datepicker

Say I have `List<DateTime>` that has 3 `DateTime` `objects`, Can I disable these 3 days in my `DatePicker` (better than let the user to choice one of them and tell him this day isn't available), Is that even doable?

Comment: `DatePicker` has Minimum and Maximum date properties, other than that you will have to implement your own logic, dosc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.datepicker?view=xamarin-forms

Answer (score 0):

Yes It's Possible with third party date picker; use this [XamForms.Controls.Calendar](https://github.com/rebeccaXam/XamForms.Controls.Calendar/wiki)
Below in my code I'm disabling Weekend days;[Demo Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuVAe.png)

Here you can add special dates in this control; if it is **SAT** or **SUN** then set your special dates  and its property **Selectable = false**

```
for (DateTime i = MinimumDate; i < MinimumDate.AddMonths(2); i = i.AddDays(1))
{
    if ((i.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday) || (i.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday))
    {
        SpecDate.Add(new SpecialDate(i)
        {
            TextColor = Color.Gray,
            Selectable = false,
            FontSize = 10,
            BackgroundPattern = new BackgroundPattern(1)
            {
                Pattern = new List
                {
                    new Pattern
                    {
                        WidthPercent = 1f,
                        HightPercent = 1f,
                        Color = Color.Transparent,Text = "",
                        TextSize =11,
                        TextAlign=TextAlign.CenterBottom
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```